# What does "Top level element is not completed" mean?

Tags: android, xml

I'm really new to this and I've searched for answers but none seem relevant. When I build my android project I have an error. See at the bottom of this xml. Where do I go to find this "top level element" and why might it be incomplete?:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".PhotoAlbum3">

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Previous Pic"
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Next Picture"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ivids"/>
```

*//@drawable/ivids is underlined with the error 'top level element is not completed"

Comment: No, I still haven't solved it. Today I'll go to my school and see if I can find help.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to close the root tag first and write `xml` like this, You can copy this which I've edited

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".PhotoAlbum3">

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Previous Pic"
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next Picture"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ivids"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

If you are still getting the error then press <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> and choose `Uninject language/reference` option.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you haven't posted your entire XML, you haven't closed your `RelativeLayout` tag.

[Android Layout Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".PhotoAlbum3">

<Button
style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Previous Pic"
android:id="@+id/btn"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Next Picture"
android:id="@+id/button2"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/iv"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/ivids"/>   

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think I just didn't copy the whole text. I'm still getting the error with the </RelativeLayout> end tag

Answer (score 0):

I think it is an android studio bug. I get this tiny error. I just close and open the xml file and this error gone